# Simplify do notation

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to perform very simple parsing of time string

```hs
data Time = Time Int Int Int String

-- example input: 07:00:00AM
timeParser :: Parser Time
timeParser = do
    hh <- digits
    _ <- colon
    mm <- digits
    _ <-colon
    ss <- digits
    p <- period
    return $ Time hh mm ss p
```

Is there any way to simplify the `do` block with a combination of `(>>)` and `(>>=)` operators?

Comment: What would you consider "simpler"?

Comment: @jwodder I think I am looking for an one-liner combination of parsers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your `Parser` should also be an instance of [`Applicative`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Applicative):

```
timeParser :: Parser Time
timeParser = Time <$> (digits <* colon) <*> (digits <* colon) <*> digits <*> period
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

By simply tossing out the results of `colon`, a shortened version of your function (that still uses do-notation) might look something like this:

```
timeParser :: Parser Time
timeParser = do
  hh <-          digits
  mm <- colon >> digits
  ss <- colon >> digits
  p  <- period
  return $ Time hh mm ss p
```

Any further desugaring of the do-notation would sacrifice readability.

That being said, I really like Zeta's answer and the applicative style of programming in Haskell floors me.

Comment: Thanks this is pretty great as well